# Defining protocol on Info.plist in plugin for ionic app is not working bluetooth printer zebra ios

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I am trying to develop a plugin to print with my ionic app using zebra bluetooth printer.

It gives me an error when trying to print saying "opennig session failed as protocol com.zebra.rawport is not declared in Info.plist"

Here is my Info.plist file described in :

[Image with info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8W81.png)

I dont really know what to do if i am putting the protocol on the file.

Here I add the plugin.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0" id="com.ecuaquimica.zebraPrinterBluetooth" version="0.0.1">

    <name>ZebraPrinter Bluetooth</name>

    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.4.0"/>
        </engines>

        <js-module src="www/zebraPrinterBluetooth.js" name="zebraPrinterBluetooth">
            <clobbers target="zebraPrinterBluetooth"/>
        </js-module>

        <platform name="android">
            <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
            </config-file>
            <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
                <feature name="ZebraPrinterBluetooth">
                    <param name="android-package" value="com.ecuaquimica.plugin.ZebraPrinterBluetooth"/>
                </feature>
            </config-file>
            <source-file src="src/android/ZebraPrinterBluetooth.java" target-dir="src/com/zebraPrinterBluetooth/plugin/"/>
            <source-file src="src/android/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar" target-dir="libs"/>
        </platform>

        <platform name="ios">

            <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
                <feature name="ZebraPrinterBluetooth">
                    <param name="ios-package" value="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin"/>
                </feature>
            </config-file>

            <header-file src="src/ios/ZebraPrinterBluetooth.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin"/>
            <source-file src="src/ios/ZebraPrinterBluetooth.m" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin"/>

            <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedExternalAccesoryProtocols">
                <array>
                    <string>com.zebra.rawport</string>
                </array>
            </config-file>

            <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="Required Background modes">
                <array>
                    <string>App Communicates with an accesory</string>
                </array>
            </config-file>

            <source-file src="src/ios/libZSDK_API.a" framework="true"/>

            <framework src="ExternalAccesory.framework" />

            <header-file src="src/ios/include/DiscoveredPrinter.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/DiscoveredPrinterNetwork.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/FieldDescriptionData.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/FileUtil.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/FormatUtil.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/GraphicsUtil.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/MagCardReader.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/MfiBtPrinterConnection.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/NetworkDiscoverer.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/PrinterStatus.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/PrinterStatusMessages.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/SGD.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/SmartCardReader.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/TcpPrinterConnection.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/ToolsUtil.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/ZebraErrorCode.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/ZebraPrinter.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/ZebraPrinterConnection.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/ZebraPrinterFactory.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>
            <header-file src="src/ios/include/ZplPrintMode.h" target-dir="ZebraPrinterBluetoothPlugin/Headers"/>

        </platform>

    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the .plist file, see [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW4): UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols (double 's').

Comment: I feel really dumb thans for your help!